# Dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, grub2, dual-boot, external-hdd

I can't boot into Windows 7 from GRUB, or can't boot into Linux from Windows 7
I have 2 HDD, on 1 I have Windows 7 and on other I have Linux. Both HDD are working properly.

Help me to correct dual boot.

```
Boot Info Script e7fc706 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 31Jan2013]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 1 for (,msdos1)/grub.
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and uses an 
    embedded config file:

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    search.fs_uuid cb0e9d75-552c-4509-b720-d914e2375b4c root hd1,msdos1  
    set prefix=($root)/grub
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -----.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda5 starts 
                       at sector 2048.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sda6 starts 
                       at sector 2048.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext3
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg /grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sdb5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext3
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 12.10 
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab

sdb6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7/2008: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1               2,048       206,847       204,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2    *        206,848   272,631,807   272,424,960   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3         272,631,808   639,633,407   367,001,600   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda4         639,633,408 1,953,521,663 1,313,888,256   f W95 Extended (LBA)
/dev/sda5         639,635,456 1,059,065,855   419,430,400   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda6       1,059,067,904 1,953,521,663   894,453,760   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *          2,048       976,895       974,848  83 Linux
/dev/sdb2             978,942   301,758,463   300,779,522   5 Extended
/dev/sdb5             978,944    49,805,311    48,826,368  83 Linux
/dev/sdb6          49,807,360   293,945,343   244,137,984  83 Linux
/dev/sdb7         293,947,392   301,758,463     7,811,072  82 Linux swap / Solaris


Drive: sdc _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdc: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdc1    *             63   488,392,064   488,392,002   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        323AD4403AD3FF33                       ntfs       System Reserved
/dev/sda2        EC44E6E344E6AF8E                       ntfs       Windows 7
/dev/sda3        6C2478182477E38C                       ntfs       Softwares
/dev/sda5        54B6B371B6B351EA                       ntfs       Games
/dev/sda6        3A04C1F004C1AF67                       ntfs       Movies
/dev/sdb1        6570258e-4efb-4cdb-91af-5bd97ff51912   ext3       
/dev/sdb5        543b5815-ffa5-4c88-b172-98587aca26ee   ext3       
/dev/sdb6        083db3df-5599-4f0b-94d6-1d6ea52ece6e   ext4       
/dev/sdb7        92d881dc-4a65-4b0a-aeac-62661734083b   swap       
/dev/sdc1        AAD80849D80815EB                       ntfs       Other

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda3        /media/Softwares         fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda5        /media/Games             fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda6        /media/dhananjay/Movies  fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdb5        /                        ext3       (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdb6        /home                    ext4       (rw)
/dev/sdc1        /media/Other             fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvzW23Nb5Ls

Comment: dude i have 2 hdd i already install linux on 1 hdd and windows 7 on 1st hdd. I can see win 7 entry in grub menu but when I select win 7 it gives me error " Disk read error press ctrl + alt + del to restart "  and my both hdd are working properly I can boot into win 7 by selecting 1st hdd prob bios

Comment: That's a problem with Windows, dhanu. Install Ubuntu in a free partition or a hard drive for... Ubuntu installation will automatically detect Windows installation in the other hard drive...Then will be offered to chose either Ubuntu or Windows at startup. Make sure you partition table is msdos/MBR not GTP.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these commands. They help fix many dual-boot issues like yours.

```
sudo os-prober; sudo update-grub
```